# <Application>Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched

Tags: android-emulator

i am using Android since 2 months or so. and last week i have installed Android on a PC . it was working good.

but since yesterday , when i try to run application it starts the Emulator and got stuck at a place

***[TouchCalculator] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...***

after a long wait.. it shows a message and fails to load ..

kindly help me in this regard.

Thanks A.Q.Ghouri

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the problem. The following solved my problem:
**Just Create a new AVD and Delete the previous one**
go to *Window* > *AVD Manager* > and create a new one and run the application again.
It nicely works within 2-3 minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

I installed generic AVD and the problem was fixed